# GazeboRosOpenniKinect vs GazeboRosDepthCamera

Tags: kinect, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The ROS Groovy simulator_gazebo package has both GazeboRosOpenniKinect and GazeboRosDepthCamera plugins. Which one is preferred? What is the difference?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1530/gazeborosopennikinect-vs-gazeborosdepthcamera/) by [jon-weisz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/232/jon-weisz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think they are very similar, but the OpenniKinnect plugin will mimic the output of Kinect.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhi kashyap](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/809/abhi-kashyap/) on 2014-07-04**:
Is there any way so that the camera does not take pictures continuously but at some discrete random intervals?